# Install shp2pgsql without PostGIS

Tags: postgis, ubuntu, shp2pgsql

I have Django app that handles an uploaded shapefile and extracts the geom using shp2pgsql. As the Django app and the PostgreSQL(PostGIS) are in different docker containers, I cannot call shp2pgsql directly from Django container. Is there a way to install shp2pgsql without installing postgresql in the Django container?

Comment: you could use ogr2ogr from GDAL in your Django container instead.  That can be installed without postgres. https://gdal.org/

Comment: ogr2ogr Is part of gdak and can output sql instead of executing an insertion

Comment: (* gdal) sorry for the typo